# FileWriter removing the Java.awt.Point

Tags: java, filewriter

I am creating a program that will outprint the coordinates of a location. When it prints it out to the file, it looks like this:

```
Car id   distance #spots

java.awt.Point[x=1,y=1]
java.awt.Point[x=2,y=0]

java.awt.Point[x=1,y=0]

car0 java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0] java.awt.Point[x=1,y=0] 1

car1 java.awt.Point[x=2,y=0] java.awt.Point[x=2,y=0] 2
```

I am trying to get rid of the java.awt.Point from showing up so it only shows the coordinates.

Heres my code:
    public void saveGrid(File name) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

```
    ArrayList<Car> cars = getCars();
    ArrayList<ParkingSpot> spots = getSpots();

    PrintWriter fileWriter;
    try {
        fileWriter = new PrintWriter(name);


        fileWriter.println("hi");

        fileWriter.println("\n\nCar id   distance #spots\n");
        fileWriter.println(getPartyLocation());


        for(ParkingSpot spot: spots){
            fileWriter.println(spot.getLocation());
            fileWriter.println("");
        }
        for (Car car: cars) {
            fileWriter.println(car.getId() + " " + car.getStart() + " " + car.getLocation() + " " + car.getNumSpotsTried());
            fileWriter.println("");

        }



        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("FileWriting error:" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add `car.getLocation()` to the string, you're adding a `Point` object. It's implicitly converted to string with `toString()`. The `toString` method for `java.awt.Point` is:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "[x=" + x + ",y=" + y + "]";
}
```

which is essentially:

```
public String toString() {
    return "java.awt.Point[x=" + x + ",y=" + y + "]";
}
```

Instead of relying on this default behavior, you can do the following:

```
// Get the car's location.
Point loc = car.getLocation();

// Create a string representation: [x,y]
String locString = "[" + loc.x + "," + loc.y + "]";

// Add the line with all the other stuff
fileWriter.println(car.getId() + " " + car.getStart() + " " + locString + " "
  + car.getNumSpotsTried());
```

Answer (score 1):

The `java.awt.Point` stuff is being printed because your gridSave method is implicitly calling `java.awt.Point.toString()` ... and that's what it produces.  (A typical `toString()` is designed to produce debug output, and including the classname is appropriate in that context.)

Your possibilities are:

- Write your own `Point` class with a `toString()` method that outputs the location in the format you want.
- Create a subclass of `java.awt.Point` that overrides the `toString()` method.
- Don't use the `Point.toString()` method.  Instead, write a `String formatLocation(Point)` method to format a `Point` how you want, and use it in your `gridSave` method.